# Problema al actualizar con ID de otra tabla en CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estas son las 3 tablas que tengo:

**ci_comments** : comment_id, email, website, body.

**ci_relationship** : id, comment_id, user_id.

**ci_users** : user_id, username, email, biography.

El problema es que estoy intentando conseguir data de dos tablas, una es la de ci_comments que muestra todo el contenido de los comentarios y la otra tabla para conseguir el user_id del que comento.

Tengo esto en mi metodo edit en el controller de Comments:

```
// Field Rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_id', 'User ID', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'body', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'Status', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            $data['item'] = $this->Comments_model->get($id);

            // AQUI ES DONDE NECESITO AYUDA - No estoy ni seguro si es que debería pasar una variable o no //
// Recuerden que el user_id debe de venir de la table ci_relationship
            $data['commentator'] = $this->Comments_model->get_userID($userID);

            // /AQUI ES DONDE NECESITO AYUDA //

            // Select Comment Author ID
            $user_options = array();
            $user_options[0] = 'Select Comment Author ID';

            $user_list = $this->User_model->get_list();
            foreach($user_list as $username){
                $user_options[$username->id] = $username->username;
            }

            $data['user_options'] = $user_options;

            // Load template
            $this->template->load('admin', 'default', 'comments/edit', $data);

        }
```

He aqui la funcion del Model que utilizo para conseguir el contenido del actual comentario:

```
public function get($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('ci_comments');
        return $query->row();
    }
```

Y aqui la funcion que estoy tratando de crear para conseguir el user_id del comentario:

```
public function get_userID($userID){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('user_id', $userID);
    $this->db->where('type', $this->type);
    $query = $this->db->get('ci_relationship');
    return $query->row();
}
```

Basicamente quiero mostrar un dropdown en donde se supone que se debe de mostrar todos los usuarios que han hecho un comentario pero no sin antes mostrar el usuario especifico del comentario:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Author ID', 'user_id');  ?>
        <?php echo form_dropdown('user_id', $user_options, $commentator->user_id, array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
    </div>
```

NOTE: El user_id deberia mostrarse en el tercer parametro $commentator->user_id pero me muestra null, ahora si lo cambio a $commentator['user_id] sigue con lo mismo.

Espero poder haberme explicado bien, de otra manera no me importaria  editar la pregunta para dar mas detalles.